# Check if one or multiple checkboxes is selected

Tags: html, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes for signing up to a newsletter which saves multiple values.

When the user selects one or multiple checkboxes I need another (hidden) checkbox to also be selected automatically and saved to the database. My problem is I don't know how to automatically get the hiddensetting checkbox selected?

```
<div class="col-us-6 col-xs-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[]" value="2317|2325|2333|2341|2349|2374|2399|2424"<?php if (@in_array(2317, $member_values['section'])) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>> Option 1
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-us-6 col-xs-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[]" value="2318|2326|2334|2342|2350|2375|2400|2425"<?php if (@in_array(2318, $member_values['section'])) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>> Option 2
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-us-6 col-xs-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[]" value="2319|2327|2335|2343|2351|2376|2401|2426"<?php if (@in_array(2319, $member_values['section'])) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>> Option 3
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-us-6 col-xs-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[]" value="2320|2328|2336|2344|2352|2377|2402|2427"<?php if (@in_array(2320, $member_values['section'])) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>> Option 4
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-us-6 col-xs-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[]" value="2321|2329|2337|2345|2353|2378|2403|2428"<?php if (@in_array(2321, $member_values['section'])) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>> Option 5
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-us-6 col-xs-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[]" value="2322|2330|2338|2346|2354|2379|2404|2429"<?php if (@in_array(2322, $member_values['section'])) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>> Option 6
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-us-6 col-xs-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[]" value="2323|2331|2339|2347|2355|2380|2405|2430"<?php if (@in_array(2323, $member_values['section'])) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>> Option 7
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-us-6 col-xs-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section[]" value="2324|2332|2340|2348|2356|2381|2406|2431"<?php if (@in_array(2324, $member_values['section'])) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>> Option 8
        </label>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Hidden setting -->
<input type="checkbox" name="hiddensetting" value="1"<?php if (@$member_values['hiddensetting']) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>>
```

Comment: Do you have access to any javascript frameworks, or do you need the solution in vanilla javascript? It looks like you are using bootstrap so you have access to JQUERY?

Comment: Why do you need the hidden checkbox saved? why not just save on checkbox checked using ajax, or just iterate through all the controls and then save when you postback?

Comment: Yes I know its a little strange, but the visible checkboxes saves in some special field for the newsletter and the hidden one is used to set if the user should be submitted to a certain list.